# chromecast taking long time to hide chromecat button when chromecast powered off

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented chromecast successfully and is working fine, but problem is 'when i powered off chromecast device then it's delegate taking long time to hide cast button'.

I want to immediately hide the chrome cast button when chromecast device is unplugged or powered off.

Answer (score 0):

You can't immediately do that; it may take up to 2 minutes (most cases it is less than that) and that is when the mDNS record expires.